# Automate managed package assembling

Tags: managed-package, deployment, automation, package.xml

We are developing some functionality in our sandboxes, keeping everything in git repo and merging together from time to time. When the release time comes, we usually just need to publish some managed package based on what we've developed so far. And every time we are creating managed package by manually clicking from web UI interface on each artifact presented in our package.xml.

So here is the question: is it possible somehow to avoid doing this routine and error-prone stuff? Our package.xml contains list of artifacts which should be put into the package. Can SF somehow generate package for us based on provided package.xml? Ant? External Tools?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The [Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm) object can update the contents of a package. The format is identical to the package.xml file. You can use Force.com IDE, Ant, Salesforce DX, etc.